# Bizarre WPF DataGrid issue

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

This is the most strange error I've seen yet! Pulling my hair out!

I have a Window with a DataGrid which is bound to a generic List[object] with auto generated columns.

Internally we have 2 distinct PC build. On one type, the window displays (correctly) as follows:
[image: When it displays correctly]

and this is on the other PC build type (incorrect):
[image: When it displays badly]

Both types of PCs are Win 7 x64 builds, but the main difference are the video cards.
In both cases I am running the exact same binary and config.

The code for my window is here:

```
<Window x:Class="FicClient.Server.ComponentWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" Title="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=Section}" Height="418" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Icon="/FicClient;component/images/Visualpharm-Must-Have-Information.ico">
    <DockPanel>
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="4" Background="Azure">
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">Note: Component data is a snapshot and does not update</TextBlock>
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="Button_Click">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image  Source="/FicClient;component/images/excel.ico" Stretch="Uniform" Height="25" />
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5,0">Copy</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </DockPanel>
        <DataGrid Name="DataGridComponents" ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneTime}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True" >
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

For debug purposes, when the window opens it also displays a popup, telling me how many items are in the list and in both cases that number is the same and correct. And yet, on one PC type it's just FUBAR.

Has anyone come across this kind of issue before?
Is there anything else I can do to debug it?

** UPDATE with selected answer **

The trouble was indeed that the behaviour seems different on machine with 4.0 & 4.5 installed vs only 4.0, even though the app is compiled against 4.0

The solution for me was to generate the columns manually. What I did is bind an event-handler to DataContextChanged on the DataGrid, then in the handler do this:

```
private void DataGridComponents_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
    if (dataGrid == null) return;
    var rows = dataGrid.DataContext as List<object>;
    if (rows == null) return;
    if (rows.Count == 0) return;
    var first = rows[0];
    foreach (var property in first.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var column = new DataGridTextColumn
        {
            Header = property.Name,
            Binding = new Binding(property.Name)
        };
        column.Binding.StringFormat = "{0:0.00}";
        dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how is your grid even taking the DataTemplate as you have put them in the resources with x:Key values but have not used them in the Grid...? Try removing the x:Key from the DataTemplates.

Comment: Yep, I've removed the unnecessary templates, recompiled and it's still exactly the same. They were there but not being used by the DataGrid anyway (it was just an attempt to limit the number of decimal places for doubles).

Comment: Your two windows borders look differently. Maybe the difference in PCs is their Windows Desktop style (Win7 transparent vs Classic)?

Comment: I tried setting classic on the good machine and it was fine. I will try setting win7 theme in the bad machine tomorrow to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @doerig it's compiled to .Net 4.0. Does it make a difference if 4.0 and 4.5 is installed on a machine? I would think I'd still run against the 4.0 clr?

Comment: .net 4.5 is different than other .net versions.. "The .NET Framework 4.5 replaces the .NET Framework 4. When you install the .NET Framework 4.5 on a system that has the .NET Framework 4 installed, the assemblies are replaced." .net 4.5 should be highly compatible, but once I encountered a problem because I have .net 4.5 on my dev machine and had programmed something that works in .net 4.5 but not when only 4.0 is installed

Comment: @JarekMitek are you doing something with anonymous types?

Comment: How about other controls? Like text block. Are you using any default resources?

Comment: I took all the resources from this window xaml file. I guess it might inherit something from the parent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this is change in behaviour occurs because on one machine there is .NET 4.5 installed and on the other .NET 4.0

The behaviour of the WPF DataGrid seems to be a little different.
In .NET 4, the DataGrid has some issues when binding to anonymous types.

Solutions:

- Use .net 4.5 on all computers
- Define the DataGrid Columns manually
  and set AutogenerateColumns to false
- Use normal classes instead of anonymous types

replace

```
select new { Symbol = "XXX",  Quantity = 6000, ... };
```

with

```
select new Stock { Symbol = "XXX",  Quantity = 6000, ... };
```

Comment: Btw, there were no anonymous types used for this problem to occur.

Comment: what did you use then if not anonymous types? dynamic objects or some other strange feature? ;)

Comment: Ordinary classes. One point is that they were copied over the wire (ie. serialised) but I don't see how that would affect it.